# select text in next <p id="hg-name"> and append it to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys Im trying to find the the next `<p>` close to this and output its text into another div within the same page. The problem is when I do the coding and output it to the user with alert it comes out blank. Here below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.lightbox').click(function(e){
        var txt = $(this).closest("#hh-name").text()
        alert(txt);
        $('body').css('overflow-y',' hidden');

        $('<div id="overlay"></div>')
        .css('top', $(document).scrollTop())
        .css('opacity', '0')
        .animate({'opacity': '0.7'}, 'slow')
        .appendTo('body');

        $('<div id= "lightbox"></div>')
        .hide()
        .appendTo('body');

        $('<img>', {
            src: $(this).attr('href'),
            load: function() {
                positionLightboxImage();
            },
            click : function() {
                removeLightbox();
            }
        }).appendTo('#lightbox');
        return false;
    });
});

function positionLightboxImage() {
  var top = ($(window).height() - $('#lightbox').height()) / 2;
  var left = ($(window).width() - $('#lightbox').width()) / 2;
  $('#lightbox')
    .css({
      'top': top + $(document).scrollTop(),
      'left': left,
      'border': '7px solid white',
      'border-radius': '4px'
    })
    .fadeIn();
}

function removeLightbox() {
  $('#overlay, #lightbox')
    .fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).remove();
      $('body').css('overflow-y', 'auto'); // show scrollbars!
    });
}

<a class="lightbox" href="<?php echo $row_searchHH['imageURL']; ?>"><img id="hh-image" src="<?php echo $row_searchHH['imageURL']; ?>" width="90" height="90" style="margin-left:10px" /></a></div></td>
        <td style="word-wrap:break-word; font-size:20px; font-family:'Myriad Pro'; font-weight:500" width="334" height="35"><p id="hh-name"><?php echo $row_searchHH['name']; ?></p>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be useful to help you

Comment: Why don't you create a JSFiddle that illustrates the problem and remove all superfluous code?  Also, having IDs and CSS classes with the same name (lightbox) is guaranteed to cause confusion.

Comment: Here is one http://jsfiddle.net/wXYg9/

Comment: @Steve Wellens What Im trying to do is that when I click a link with class lightbox a div is created with id lightbox and the text in the <p> tag next to the the a.lightbox is appended to the #lightbox

Answer (score 0):

You are not seleclting the body element is your code is currently written.

try:

```
    $('<div id= "lightbox" />')
    .hide()
    .appendTo($('body'))
```

Notice the syntax to create elements.

You had a few problems with your code. 
The first one was using `.closest` it just doesn't do what you think it does. 
You have to use `.siblings` instead.

Then to add the actual node I went a different direction thinking it is more appropiate:

```
$('a.lightbox').click(function(e){
    var txt = $(this).siblings("#hh-name").text();
    $('<div id= "lightbox"></div>').appendTo('body');
    $('<p/>').text(txt).appendTo('#lightbox');
  });
```

You can see the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/wXYg9/6/)

Comment: whats the purpose of this code?? I am mostly having problems selecting the text next to the selector this. If you look at my code it would be line 3 and 4

Comment: Well you create a dive element with 'lightbox' id and append it to the body element

Comment: Im not having problems appending whatever it gives me to the #lightbox div but the problem is getting the text out of the <p> next to this

Comment: It is hard to tell without your html structure but try using `.find`

Comment: Hey Javier here's your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/C576s/

Using the closest selector wasn't returning anything for you (it doesn't look for siblings).
I left the debugging alerts in so you will know how to check for this kind of stuff in the future.

```
$('a.lightbox').click(
function (e)
{
    var $closest = $(this).next("#hh-name");
    alert($closest.length);

    var txt = $closest.text();
    alert(txt);

    $('<div id= "lightbox"></div>').appendTo('body');
    $('<p>' + txt + '</p>').appendTo('#lightbox');
}
```

);

Comment: That still does not work.... the first alert display 0 and the second one undefined. I have added my html/php code below. Basically what I have is a php repeating region where depending on the results from the search the image and name comes out

Comment: Still does not work...inside the <p id="hh-name"> there is a php statement returning a text field from a mysql table. I don't know if it makes a difference.

Comment: Does the jsFiddle work?   It doesn't matter what runs at the server. What matters is the HTML and JavaScript at the client.